Determinant of matrix square root
I have a complex-symmetric matrix $A$ of size $n\times n$ with positive real part $\Re(A)>0$, and I need to calculate
$$\det\left(\sqrt{A}\right)$$
in the context of calculating a Gaussian integral.
Now, if  $A$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, which is usually the case for my applications,
$$\det\left(\sqrt{A}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\lambda_i}$$
where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ refers to the principal square root.
Using numpy/scipy, however, for all matrix sizes $n$, this is considerably slower than
$\sqrt{\det(A)}$.
However, despite what is sometimes found in the literature, these two formulas are not equivalent, as the sign might be different.
My question is now if someone knows either

How to carry out the operation $\det\left(\sqrt{A}\right)$ more cheaply (in Python). From my observation, at least for small matrices, sp.linalg.sqrtm is even slower than diagonalization.
Whether there's a trick to "know" if there is a sign difference between  $\det\left(\sqrt{A}\right)$ and $\sqrt{\det(A)}$.
Another trick to speed up these calculations. I need double precision, I tried using jax, but that only gives me single precision.

In my calculations, $n$ is small, $n=2$ to $n=6$. For $n=2$ and $n=3$, I could of course calculate the eigenvalues with an explicit formula, but that does only work for these particular cases. Speed matters to me as I have to diagonalize a lot of matrices.

How exactly are you defining the square root of a matrix? Does $A$ have special properties you are using, such as $A$ being symmetric and positive definite? Or does $A$ have no such properties at all, and you want to define things for generic matrices?

@WolfgangBangerth, the OP mentions that the matrices are complex and symmetry and diagonalizable. They are not Hermitian or definite, in general, though.

Yes, my matrices are complex-symmetric (not Hermitian). I forgot to mention in my post that they also have a positive real part, Re(A)>0.

Per https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.det.html , "The determinant is computed by performing an LU factorization of the input with LAPACK routine ‘getrf’, and then calculating the product of diagonal entries of the U factor."

Right, but there are different ways of defining a square root. For example, for SPD matrices you can take a matrix derived from the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Or you use the factors of an $LL^T$ decomposition.

From my understanding, the principal square root $\sqrt{M}$ of any diagonalizable matrix $M=PDP^{-1}$ is defined as $\sqrt{M}=P\sqrt{D}P^{-1}$, where $\sqrt{D}=\text{diag}({\sqrt{\lambda_1},\dots,\sqrt{\lambda_N}})$, and each square root corresponds to the principal square root. The square root has hence the property that $\sqrt{M}\sqrt{M}=M$, i.e. I don't mean the Cholesky decomposition.
